# How to debug multi-threaded Python 2.7 app?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, debugging, pdb

The problem is to debug multi-threaded Python 2.7 app on machine that is slow for IDE like PyCharm. Remote debugging ability would be even more desired.

I tried to use pdb Python library but it seems it could only break on main thread. I could find (via Ctrl+F) word `thread` in documentation page. Also I saw in other SO questions and answers that debugging may be enabled by altering source code but it's not convenient solution. Writing single-threaded is solution but it's not cheap and simple as well.

Is there any other ways?